# MySQL: Search based on a column, each unique value in another column and max time

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to assemblethe right MySQL statement and would love to hear some input from the stack exchange community.

I have a table like this:

```
id | controller | sensor | data | time
1  | A          | TEMP   | 65   | 12:30
2  | A          | SWITCH | 0    | 12:30
3  | A          | TEMP   | 66   | 12:31
4  | A          | SWITCH | 1    | 12:31
5  | B          | SWITCH | 1    | 12:31
6  | A          | TEMP   | 67   | 12:32
7  | A          | SWITCH | 1    | 12:32
8  | B          | SWITCH | 65   | 12:32
9  | A          | TEMP   | 68   | 12:33
10 | B          | TEMP   | 65   | 12:33
11 | A          | SWITCH | 0    | 12:33
12 | B          | TEMP   | 65   | 12:34
13 | A          | HUMID  | 10   | 12:35
14 | B          | HUMID  | 10   | 12:35
```

What I really want to do is select all of the rows that have the MAX(time) for each sensor from a given controller. So the result on this table if I wanted controller A would be:

```
9  | A          | TEMP   | 68   | 12:33
11 | A          | SWITCH | 0    | 12:33
13 | A          | HUMID  | 10   | 12:35
```

One item for each sensor that has the highest time for that sensor for a given controller.

The best statement of come up with so far is:

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM `table` WHERE `sensor` = "TEMP" and `controller` = "A")

But I can only get one sensor with this (obviously) and I'm not sure how one would go about getting what I'm looking for. I almost need something like a for loop to iterate through each `sensor = * and controller = A` to find the max time but I have no idea how to implement that. You're feedback would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `join` the table back to itself using a subquery:

```
select y.id, y.controller, y.sensor, y.data, y.time
from yourtable y join (
    select controller, sensor, max(time) maxtime
    from yourtable
    group by controller, sensor
    ) t on y.controller = t.controller and 
           y.sensor = t.sensor and
           y.time = t.maxtime
where y.controller = 'A'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80e79/1)

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks to you, my project's back up and running. It's going to take quite a while for me to wrap my brain around how this works though. Thanks again!